# Keeping track of functions being called externally

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

So let's assume I'd write a framework,

and I need a part of this to keep track of a user defined function and when it is called. I do have a pointer to said function, but that's it, there is nothing in the function that will help me as I'll keep track of it externally.
It should look the sorts of this:

```
if(someFuncPtr->isCalled()) {
    doSomeThings();
}
```

thanks in advance

Folling

Comment: Unless you can impose some restrictions on the function you want to observe, that's impossible. Well, technically, you could make use of debugging techniques, but that would be platform dependent and very slow.

Comment: As it stands this appears to be an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Why do you need to keep track of calls to this function?  What is the underlying issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: Make a global vector. Everytime a function is called add its name inside the function into it. Now this way you can track the order of functions called, how many times a particular function is called and what not!